# Generate road mesh from a graph

Tags: c++, procedural-generation, unreal-4, graph

I want to generate a mesh for the entire road network(later I'll probably want to split it into chunks but for now this will do).

My road network is stored as a `TArray` of pointers to a struct that contains the node location and pointers to each connected road(it's up to 4 nodes, each one has a direction).

```
struct FRoadNode
{
    int radius;
    float angle;
    TWeakPtr<FRoadNode> topNode;
    TWeakPtr<FRoadNode> bottomNode;
    TWeakPtr<FRoadNode> rightNode;
    TWeakPtr<FRoadNode> leftNode;
}
```

The road is following a **polar** grid. (see Frostpunk for example, it's almost exactly like that)

Each arc will be divided by its length to have as little vers as possible while keeping a nice curve.
If 2 line segments get too close the will be merged at the intersection point. (3rd example below, still not sure about this one...)
If 2 intersections are too close together they will be merged.

Here's the general idea of how I was thinking of generating the mesh:
[image: just an idea]

I'm pretty new to generating mesh programmatically and to UE C++... so..
**1.** Is there a nice algorithm out there that will make my life a little bit easier?
**2.** How should I approach it?
**3.** Should I connect the road segment verts with the intersections verts?
**4.** Are there some advanced techniques that I need to know about?

BTW I saw somewhere a way to generate the road mesh by connecting all the nodes then extrude the edges, but I can't find it and I have no idea how this method called, If you know what I'm talking about, please tell what it's called\provide links.